# How to access mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection, node.js-connect

This is my app.js file.

```
require("dotenv").config()
// async errors

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const connectDB = require("./db/connect")

const notFoundMiddleware = require("./middleware/not-found");
const errorMiddleware = require("./middleware/error-handler");

// middleware
app.use(express.json())

// routes

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Store API</h1><a href="/api/v1/products">products route</a>')
})

// products route

app.use(notFoundMiddleware)
app.use(errorMiddleware)

const port = 5000

const start = async () => {
    try {
        // connectDB
        await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI)
        app.listen(port, console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}..`))
    } catch (error) { 
        console.log(error);
    }
}

start();
```

This is my connect.js file.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = (url) => {
  return mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

So, I want to access my DB on MongoDB. I created a .env file and wrote there my MongoDB application code. Then I want to process it on my app .js but when I wrote and ran this code `await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI)` it returned back an authentication error.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you sure that `process.env.MONGO_URI)` has a value? Try to log it

Comment: yes, absolutely

Comment: Make connectDB function async and await mongoose.connect

Answer (score 0):

to access mongodb try this way

```
>>app.js

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 3000;
const connectDB=require('./config/db');// DB connection
connectDB()


const notFoundMiddleware = require("./middleware/not-found");
const errorMiddleware = require("./middleware/error-handler");

// middleware
app.use(express.json())

// routes

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Store API</h1><a href="/api/v1/products">products route</a>')
})

// products route

app.use(notFoundMiddleware)
app.use(errorMiddleware)



app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console .log(`server  is connected to port ${(PORT)}...`);  
});
```

for mongodb connection

> > db.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

function connectDB() {


  mongoose.connect(
      process.env.MONGO_URI,
    {useNewUrlParser:true},
    ()=>console.log('connected to db...'));
}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

No need to use

```
 useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
```